# Umbraco richtext is not saved after upgrading to 4.11

Tags: asp.net, tinymce, umbraco, uriencoding

I upgraded from Umbraco 4.10 to 4.11 and now when I save a document, all fields are saved except for richtext fields where everything is deleted. Anything I type in richtext editor is lost after saving.
I've had similar problems before with other editors which were caused by html elements and could be solved by uri encoding but I never had this problem with Umbraco and TinyMce.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was a problem with some customizations that I made in TinyMce that worked well until 4.10 and not working in 4.11 . I don't know why they chose to use TinyMce, CKEditor is way better.

Answer (score 0):

Umbraco have released a patch for 4.11 called 4.11.1 and can be downloaded [here](http://umbraco.codeplex.com/releases/view/98167). So I would upgrade to this, although according to the documentation they haven't fixed anything that may affect your issue. I would also check that you have copied all the upgrade files required for 4.10 including the config/tinyMceConfig.config file. See [here](http://umbraco.codeplex.com/releases/view/91737) for the list of files/folders needed.